# dlmForecast error : "dlmForecast only works with constant models"

Tags: time-series, bayesian, state-space-models, dlm

I have a dataset with intervention dummy variable to be incorporated inside the measurement equation (let's call Lambda)

I picture my measurement and state are as below :
measurement : Lambda + Et
state : Et = ARMA(1,2) + Nt

So the error follow state specification of ARMA(1,2) process, while the measurement equation take care of Lambda.

When I try to do this under dlm package, my code is below :

## setting the dummy

```
lambda <- rep(0, length(train[,2]))
lambda[54:71] <- 1 
lambda <- ts(lambda)
```

## function to dlm

```
build <- function(par){
  dlmModReg(lambda, addInt=TRUE) + dlmModARMA(ar=par[1], ma=c(par[2], par[3]), sigma=exp(par[4]))}
fit <- dlmMLE(train[,2], parm=rep(0,4), build=build, hessian=TRUE)
filt <- dlmFilter(train[,2],mod)
smooth <- dlmSmooth(filt)
```

The code above achieved convergence, which is fantastic. And when I try to forecast this using the filt, I cannot do this as the error spits as : "dlmForecast only works with constant models"

I understand that the dlm package currently will not run forecast is the JFF is not NULL (which is true in my case, I have JFF that consist of 1 in my vector, hence it's time varying with my FF)

But, question is :

1. How should I solve this? is there any way to manipulate it?
2. If I remove the dummy and only run the ARMA(1,2), my convergence is very large... around 52. Any help and ideas how to solve it then?

Any help will be greatly appreciated... Thanks :)

Best,

Jess